# Prerequisites to compiler theory?

Tags: computer-science, compiler

It's not meant to be subjective or get advice on what would be the best path to take, but an objective list of things that must be known in order for me to pick up a book on compiler theory and understand it.

What level of mathematics, and related skills are required?

Comment: The difficult part of the compiler theory is the optimization, where you would need to very well the ISA and even the architecture of the CPU.

Comment: @m3th0dman, most of the optimisations are target-agnostic. Only instruction selection and register allocation are really target-specific, but there is nothing really complicated there, these areas are well-researched. ABI is of course target-specific, but there is no algorithmic complexity at all in it.

Comment: @SK-logic: Intelligent use of `Count Leading Zeroes` comes to mind, as well as the use of 32*32->64 multiplications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key question really is: at what level? I'm going to assuming a fairly introductory one if you're asking this question. I have only done one course on compilers, so perhaps my knowledge is too elementary, but here's what is useful to know:

- Basic 32-bit assembler, including how the stack works, and the usage of `ebp`, and the different kind of `jmp`s
- Good understanding of data structures: trees, linked lists, and some of the common algorithms associated with them (binary search, for example)
- Basic understanding of complexity theory, mainly the big O notation
- Knowledge of basic regular expressions

To be perfectly honest, if you wanted to pick up any book on compiler theory and read it, then you should have read *an introduction to compilers* and preferably implemented something basic yourself (so you get a good idea from how it works: parsing source code, generating parse trees, to code generation). After that, you can look at optimisations (e.g. `age = 4 + 5` would be compiled directly as `age = 9`, the `4+5` computation would be done once at compile time and never again).

Comment: Thank you! What level of mathematics would you recommend? This is all for starting the study of compilers.

Comment: I honestly don't feel that any abstract mathematics is required. For example: if you had to evaluate `(2 * 3) + ((4 + 5) * (6 + 7))`, which bracket would you do first? This is much less about *mathematics*, and more about *understanding* the limitations of computers and using it to their full advantage. This is about as complicated as mathematical expressions would get.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I assumed as much is because this subject is usually taught to juniors and seniors in CS curricula at different schools.

Comment: Precisely. I think the prerequisite on computer architecture is more important than mathematics. If this answers your question, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it (hollow tick under the vote count) :-)

Comment: I would add regular expressions to the list.

Comment: there is no reason a compiler has to compile to assembly of course, so in the general case you could replace the first point with any target language

Comment: @jk True, but I think until you do, you'll be missing half the picture (hidden by how magical other compilers like LLVM or gcc are). I think it's good to do assembler once, then I agree, compile to any target platform you like.

Comment: Regular expressions are irrelevant (and of course far from being a prerequisite).

Comment: I found it helpful to already know regular expressions when learning about deterministic/non-deterministic finite automata. I put 'basic' for this reason. YMMV.

Comment: @Jay, my point is that finite automata are also irrelevant

Comment: I'd also add language design to the list.  If you don't know how to recognize (and fix) an ambiguous grammar or understand operator associativity you're going to have a hard time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would be covered in any good introduction to compilers course, I don't think it necessary to know this beforehand (though I agree it's very valuable).

Answer (score 1):

Use different compilers and understand what a compiler can do, as a black box, before you adventure into writing one. Try to use different compilers from command line, see what options they have and what are the effects, what do they have in common, etc.

After that, you need to know a few things:

- Basic arithmetic
- Data structures
- Graph theory
- Computer architecture
- Formal languages (might or might not be covered in detail by the compiler book)
- Some advanced math might be required if you adventure in code optimization

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are much, much simpler than they're usually perceived. You do not need any advanced knowledge. Understanding some basics of the graph theory might help (but it is certainly not a prerequisite). Understanding the term rewriting systems would also be beneficial. But the best approach is to just start learning the compilers theory and pick up what is missing on the way.

Many things that are discussed in detail in the popular compilers textbooks are totally irrelevant to the real world practice and even to the bleeding edge modern compilers research. Chances are, you'll never need to touch the formal languages (alas, parsing *is overrated*). There is no need to understand the computer architecture in detail (although it might help). No complicated data structures are required, besides very simple trees and DAGs.

Comment: Well, if all you want to do is a simple DSL it's not too complicated.  If you want to do things like invariant code motion or escape analysis, or if you need to get into register allocation then it can get pretty intense.  One of the reasons IA-64 never took off was the lack of a good production-quality compiler early on, and Intel has some *very* good compiler engineers.

Comment: @TMN, Such problems are computationally complex (even simplest instruction selection is NP-complete), but it does not mean they're  not easy to comprehend. Even a 6 years old person is able to understand, say, the traveling salesman problem, which is more complicated than anything you'll find in a compiler. As for escape analysis you've mentioned - it is about 10 lines of Datalog. An average CRUD application is 100s times more complicated.

Comment: You find me a 6 year old that can explain the conditions required for loop-invariant code motion and I'll give them a job for life.